# DbgHelp - Get full symbol signature (function name + parameters types)

Tags: c++, symbols, signature, dbghelp

I am using [`SymEnumSymbols`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680718(v=vs.85).aspx) to get all the matching symbols to a given mask, and push them into a vector using the CALLBACK function. The problem is, that the symbol name (which is inside the `PSYMBOL_INFO` structure) is only the name of the function, and not the whole signature.. For example, I have this function:

```
TestMe!GetImageProcAddress (struct HINSTANCE__ *hi, int num)
```

When I call [`SymEnumSymbols`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680718(v=vs.85).aspx) with the mask `"TestMe!GetImageProcAddress"`, and prints the name of the matched symbol, I get:

```
printf("%s\n", pSymInfo->Name); // Prints: GetImageProcAddress
```

But I want it to print one of these:

```
TestMe!GetImageProcAddress (struct HINSTANCE__ *, int)
GetImageProcAddress (struct HINSTANCE__ *, int)
```

So my question - is there any way to get the full symbol signature (name of the function + type of parameters)? I was able to iterate through the parameters using [`SymSetContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681364(v=vs.85).aspx), then [`SymEnumSymbols`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680718(v=vs.85).aspx) and filtering with the flag `SYMFLAG_PARAMETER` - but I don't know how to get the types of the parameters..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search - I have found a solution.
After getting the index of the function, you need to enumerate it's parameters by setting the context to the specific function address using [`SymSetContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681364(v=vs.85).aspx), then calling [`SymEnumSymbols`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680718(v=vs.85).aspx) (and set it to use the context):

```
SymEnumSymbols(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, NULL, ...)
```

Then, by using the flag `SYMFLAG_PARAMETER` you can select only the function parameters. Now, using the parameter `TypeIndex`, you can search for the parameter type by calling (a lot of times) to [`SymGetTypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681349(v=vs.85).aspx). It is not simple, and there are a lot of base cases...

A really good explanation can be found here:
[HOW TO USE DBGHELP TO ACCESS TYPE INFORMATION](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/dbghelptypeinfo.html)

And an example can be found here:
[TYPEINFODUMP](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/typeinfodump.html)

Good luck!